# javascript добавление псевдоэлементов к элементу с id?

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как к элементу, который создается посредством JS добавить псевдоэлемент :after с необходимыми свойствами? Приведу пример для наглядности.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var body = document.body;
    var divMarker =  document.createElement('div');
        divMarker.id = 'marker';

    divMarker.style.position = "fixed";
    divMarker.style.top = "50%";
    divMarker.style.left = "0";
    divMarker.style.height = "0";
    divMarker.style.width = "0";
    divMarker.style.borderTop = "40px solid transparent";
    divMarker.style.borderBottom = "40px solid transparent";
    divMarker.style.borderLeft = "80px solid #f00";
    divMarker.style.fontFamily = "Arial, sans-serif";
    divMarker.style.fontWeight = "700";
    divMarker.style.color = "#fff";
    divMarker.style.lineHeight = "80px";
    divMarker.style.zIndex = "2";
    
    body.appendChild(divMarker);
};
```

```css
#marker:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "Layout";
  transform:translate(-150%, -50%);
}
```

Собственно задача - как то, что сейчас находиться в CSS, перенести в JS?
(Идеи с созданием просто дива с такими свойствами как у псевдоэлемента и помещения его внутрь #marker не предлагать)
P.S
Также буду признателен, если кто-то посоветует, как уменьшить это полотнище с 13 стилями по записе в JS.

Comment: Вы программируете не "по средствам".

Comment: в место этой колбасы со стиляси, лучше добавь  класс элеметну или по его же id пропиши все это в css...  все что можно следать в css  должно быть сделано в css

Comment: псевдоэлемент ты с помощью js не добавишь ни как...  пропиши все в стилях, как я тебе выше сказал, а с помощью js меняй классы или id? это все что ты сможешь сделать

Comment: Задача стоит в том что б элемент полностью создавался средствами JS.

Comment: Ну создай элемент с помощью JS, кто тебе мешает? Но стили пропиши ему в css, не правильно создавать элемент с помощью JS и туда же и стили пропихивать... А псевдоэлементы задаются в css,  js тут при чем?